# Multiple subtitle tracks are not encoded into mov file

Tags: ffmpeg, mov

I am trying to compile a mov file with multiple audio tracks and subtitle tracks to match. Unfortunately only the first subtitle track appears in Quicktime (Intended for Apple Devices). Looking at it compile- it appears that the second subtitle track is not being encoded using the tx3g format

**Command**

```
ffmpeg \
-i input1.mp3 \
-i input2.mp3 \
-loop 1 \
-i black.png \
-i eng.srt -i zh.srt \
-map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -map 3 -map 4 \
-c:a aac \
-c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest \
-c:s:0 mov_text \
-tag:s:s:0 tx3g \
-c:s:1 mov_text \
-tag:s:s:1 tx3g \
-metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 language=chi \
-metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:1 language=chi \
output.mov
```

**Partial output**

```
    Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874)
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 mov_text
Stream #0:4(chi): Subtitle: mov_text
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 mov_text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both subtitles have been encoded, but the tag syntax is wrong. Since codec tags apply to streams only, the initial `s` shouldn't be present. Also, since it's the same encoder, you can apply a global subtitle encoder.

So,

```
-c:s:0 mov_text \
-tag:s:s:0 tx3g \
-c:s:1 mov_text \
-tag:s:s:1 tx3g \
```

becomes

```
-c:s mov_text \
-tag:s:0 tx3g \
-tag:s:1 tx3g \
```

which can be further simplified to

```
-c:s mov_text \
-tag:s tx3g \
```

Of course, not sure that QT is failing because of this.

Comment: Hi Gyan, thanks for answering.
I didn't know about applying a global subtitle encoder. Thanks heaps. I've re-ran the command and the subtitles are now being read by quicktime.